# TfidfVectorizer : getting top dict of features_name with values

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, nlp, text-mining

Here's my data

xtra is a list of string reviews

```
xtra[1]
>> 'order monitor want makeshift area powerful old laptop take box impressed size screen wide sturdy fear wobble testing hdmi vga good selection use hdmi turn image gorgeous ip definitely make fhd shine image vivid movie amazing plenty room window great   till switch sound laptop monitor drop ball sound monitor laptop hear barely turn sound laptop hear not know money screen decide speaker minute decision plan monitor tower pc external speaker default monitor speaker mediocre look replacement monitor low price ips screen productivityworksome gaming screen suggest look monitor minimum fuss sortof recommend easy setup strongly advise external speaker order enjoy sound hook monitor'
```

yva is a list of score between 1.0 to 5.0 (float)

```
yva[1]
>> 4.0
```

Here I use train_test_split

```
xtrain, xvalid, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(xtra, yva, 
                                              stratify=yva, 
                                              random_state=0, 
                                              test_size=0.33, shuffle=True)
```

Then TfidfVectorizer

```
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, 
        strip_accents='unicode', analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
        ngram_range=(1, 1), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1, 
     )

# Fitting TF-IDF to both training and test sets (semi-supervised learning)
tfv.fit((xtrain) + (xvalid))
xtrain_tfv =  tfv.transform(xtrain) 
xvalid_tfv = tfv.transform(xvalid)
idf = tfv.idf_
features_name= (dict(zip(tfv.get_feature_names(), idf)))
sorted_scores = sorted(features_name.items, key= operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for item in sorted_scores:
    print ("{} Score: {}".format(item[0], item[1]))
```

The error I received

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-c215b51ed9ad> in <module>
     10 idf = tfv.idf_
     11 features_name= (dict(zip(tfv.get_feature_names(), idf)))
---> 12 sorted_scores = sorted(features_name.items, key= operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
     13 for item in sorted_scores:
     14     print ("{} Score: {}".format(item[0], item[1]))

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

the result that I aiming for is something like this

```
machine  Score: 0.513720
learning Score: 0.513720
about    Score: 0.256860
subject  Score: 0.256860
phd      Score: 0.256860
and      Score: 0.256860
my       Score: 0.256860
is       Score: 0.256860
reading  Score: 0.195349
```

Did I do anything wrong or are there some better ways to solve the problem?

Comment: what is `operator`?

Comment: it is an python module I found a person used to getting the answer I was looking for. [here is the source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)